# How do I print every nth match using awk

Tags: xml, split, awk

I am trying to split a large xml file into several smaller files. I found a solution to split each node into it's own file:

```
awk '/<mono/{close("row"count".xml");count++}count{f="row"count".xml";print $0 > f}' file.xml
```

The above code matches every "mono" node and outputs it to a file names row{rownumber}.xml. How can I print every 20 matches to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say keep your "count" variable, and you just need to change the way you build your filename:  `f="row" int(count/20) ".xml"`

<strike>You don't have to explicitly close the file.  All open files will be closed when awk exits.</strike>  Given the comments, I'll strike that remark.  Note in the code below, a file will be closed up to 20 times, but reopened as required.

```
awk '
  /<mono/ {close f; count++; f = "row" int(count/20) ".xml"} 
  count {print >> f}
' file.xml
```

Comment: From the `gawk` `info` file: "Here are some of the reasons for closing an output file: ... To write numerous files, successively, in the same 'awk' program. If the files aren't closed, eventually 'awk' may exceed a system limit on the number of open files in one process.  It is best to close each one when the program has finished writing it."

Comment: If there are 30,000,000 records, then closing each file is necessary.

Comment: This is simple and achieves what I needed. Although I'm stil not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain two counts - the current one and a repeat count.  Only do the current activity (print the tag) when the repeat count modulo 20 is at the appropriate value (0 and 1, in the code shown):

```
awk '/<mono/ { if (repeat++ % 20 == 0) { close("row"count".xml"); count++ } }
     count && repeat % 20 == 1 { f = "row"count".xml"; print $0 > f}' file.xml
```

The '== 1' condition in the second condition is a little untidy; there's probably a better way to handle that logic.

Note that your code detects '`<monotonous>`' as being Mono too.

---

Grouping records 1-20 in file1, 21-40 in file2, etc...

The same general idea applies...you have a file number and a matching record number, and you handle them appropriately.  Tested code:

```
awk '/<mono/ {   if (recno > 1 && recno % 20 == 0) { close(file); count++;}
                 if (recno % 20 == 0) { file = "row" count ".xml" }
                 print $0 > file
                 recno++
             }' file.xml
```

The first file will be `row.xml`.  Subsequent files are `row1.xml`, etc.

I tested this on a file like this:

```
<mono> <tonous val=001/> </mono>
ignore
<mono> <tonous val=002/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=003/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=004/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=005/> </mono>
ignore
<mono> <tonous val=006/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=007/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=008/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=009/> </mono>
ignore
<mono> <tonous val=010/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=011/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=012/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=013/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=014/> </mono>
ignore
<mono> <tonous val=015/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=016/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=017/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=018/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=019/> </mono>
ignore
<mono> <tonous val=020/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=021/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=022/> </mono>
<mono> <tonous val=023/> </mono>
ignore
<mono> <tonous val=024/> </mono>
...
```

It contained 100 `<mono>` lines and a sprinkling of `ignore` lines (some repeated).  It produced files `row.xml`, `row1.xml`, ... `row4.xml` with 20 lines in each.  This was tested on MacOS X 10.6.6 with the standard (BSD) `awk`.

Comment: I think this is heading in the right direction, but since I am printing to "row"count".xml" I still get separate files for each node. I tried to print to "row"repeat".xml" and I do get 1 file for every 20 lines, however I only get 1 node in each file.

Comment: I guess I worded the question wrong. I want to print line 1-20, 21-40, etc into separate file.

Comment: @spyderman4g63: Move the `print` to it's own `{}` block after the other two.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Is there a different approach I should be taking other than using awk?